# Can't read or mount microSD card (ext4) on Asus X205T (Q4OS)

Tags: mount, sd-card, lsblk

I'm having a hard time with my microSD card on an Asus X205T. I can see the device with lsblk, but it can't be mounted and read, it doesn't read the filesystem and stuff.

Distro: Q4OS 32-bit, Filesystem: ext4

Kernel: Linux version 4.19.0-16-686-pae (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19)

1. It is not a hardware issue because the microSD card worked on the same laptop with Windows earlier this week.
2. It is not a microSD card issue because I tried several microSD cards and they all worked on another PC.
3. [This fix from wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA#microSD_Card_Reader) didn't work.
4. When I launch GParted this error occurs: `Input/output error during read on /dev/mmcblk2`. Eventually GParted doesn't show the device at all.

Results of `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk2 /mnt/sdcard` :

```
mount: /mnt/sdcard: can't read superblock on /dev/mmcblk2.
```

Results of `lsblk` :

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk2      179:0    0   58G  0 disk
mmcblk1      179:256  0 29.1G  0 disk
├─mmcblk1p1  179:257  0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─mmcblk1p2  179:258  0 27.7G  0 part /
└─mmcblk1p3  179:259  0  976M  0 part [SWAP]
mmcblk1boot0 179:512  0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk1boot1 179:768  0    4M  1 disk
```

Results of `udisksctl info -b /dev/mmcblk2` :

```
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/mmcblk2:
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block:
    Configuration:              []
    CryptoBackingDevice:        '/'
    Device:                     /dev/mmcblk2
    DeviceNumber:               45824
    Drive:                      '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/SA64G_0x2967a02d'
    HintAuto:                   true
    HintIconName:
    HintIgnore:                 false
    HintName:
    HintPartitionable:          true
    HintSymbolicIconName:
    HintSystem:                 false
    Id:
    IdLabel:
    IdType:
    IdUUID:
    IdUsage:
    IdVersion:
    MDRaid:                     '/'
    MDRaidMember:               '/'
    PreferredDevice:            /dev/mmcblk2
    ReadOnly:                   false
    Size:                       62260248576
    Symlinks:                   /dev/disk/by-id/mmc-SA64G_0x2967a02d
                                /dev/disk/by-path/platform-PNP0FFF:00
```

Results of `dmesg | tail` :

```
[ 4713.099537] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4713.099571] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 4713.106012] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4713.110676] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4713.117095] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4713.123469] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4713.123576] Dev mmcblk2: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 4713.131799] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4713.137274] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk2, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4713.149637]  mmcblk2: unable to read partition table
```

Comment: "they all work on other PC" -- do they work in Linux? same kernel?

Comment: which kernel version? (`uname -r`)

Comment: @Andra It was missleading on my part... SD card works through SD=>USB adapter on this PC and it works via SD card reader on any other PC. Also I probably should mention that i have troubles with 32 bit OS.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Linux version 4.19.0-16-686-pae (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19)

Comment: Your kernel already includes the patches for that reader, so it's likely this is a physical interface problem between reader and card.